# this->Model-save not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm modifying the API system developed by my colleague in CakePHP 2.7 . For some reason he was using $this->query("INSERT INTO...") logic, rather than $this->Model->save. Ofcourse, the hired pentesters found this as the most critical vulnerability, but I can't get $this->Model->save to save the data.

The relevant bits of code:

APIController.php:

```
public $uses = array('ApiLog', 'ClientRecords', 'Client','TestingAPIStat','TestingAPIPool','Logging');

public function afterFilter() {

$l_t_n = $this->Logging->table;

$this->Logging->query("INSERT INTO $l_t_n VALUES ('$username', '$clientCode', '$surname', '$address1', '$address2', '$address3', '$address4', '$address5', '$address6', '$address7','$address8' , '$address9', '$postcode', '$dob', '$forename', '$title', '$home_telephone','$work_telephone' , '$mobile_telephone', '$email_address', '$ip', '$now', $dur_query, $dur_calc, $dur, '$code', $countids, $init_pool_size, \"$string_query\",$r_id,$tgood,$tbad,$treturner);");
```

Model Logging.php:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Logging extends AppModel 
{   
    public $useTable = "logging";
}
```

The above code does work and inserts new records into table. When I modify the code to use this->Logging->save($logging_values) it doesn't insert the new record, however $this->Logging->save returns true.

$logging_values array structure and contents that I'm trying to save:

```
    Array
(
    [Logging] => Array
        (
            [Request_ID] => aa11
            [add1] => 5
            [add2] => 5
            [add3] => 5
            [add4] => 5
            [add5] => 5
            [add6] => 5
            [add7] => 5
            [add8] => 5
            [add9] => 5
            [calc_duration] => 5
            [client_code] => 5
            [dob] => 
            [email_address] => 5
            [firstname] => 5
            [home_telephone] => 5
            [init_pool_size] => 5
            [mobile_telephone] => 5
            [overall_duration] => 5
            [pool_records] => 5
            [pool_size] => 5
            [postcode] => 5
            [query_duration] => 5
            [returned_code] => 5
            [submitted_time] => 
            [surname] => 5
            [title] => 5
            [total_bad] => 5
            [total_good] => 5
            [total_returner] => 5
            [user_ip] => 5
            [username] => 5
            [work_telephone] => 5
        )

)
```

Logging table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `logging` ( 
    `username` Text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `client_code` VarChar( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `surname` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add1` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add2` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add3` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add4` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add5` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add6` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add7` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add8` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `add9` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `postcode` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `dob` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `firstname` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `title` VarChar( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `home_telephone` VarChar( 45 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `mobile_telephone` VarChar( 45 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `work_telephone` VarChar( 45 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `email_address` VarChar( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `user_ip` VarChar( 45 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `submitted_time` DateTime NULL,
    `query_duration` Double( 22, 0 ) NULL,
    `calc_duration` Double( 22, 0 ) NULL,
    `overall_duration` Double( 22, 0 ) NULL,
    `returned_code` VarChar( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `pool_size` Int( 11 ) NULL,
    `init_pool_size` Int( 11 ) NULL,
    `pool_records` Text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `Request_ID` Int( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    `total_good` Int( 11 ) NULL,
    `total_bad` Int( 11 ) NULL,
    `total_returner` Int( 11 ) NULL )
CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The code I'm using

```
        if($this->Logging->save($logging_values, false))
            {  echo "success";};
        debug($this->Logging->validationErrors); //show validationErrors
        debug($this->Logging->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false));
```

I do see the 'susccess' message, but nothing gets saved. When I try to save text into the integer database column 'Request_ID' I get internal server response 500. Not sure how else to debug this? The debug statements don't show anything, though debug option is set to 2 in core.php

Comment: Check whether the `debug` option is still set to `2` when that code is being reached. Also check whether the `sql_dump` element is actually used in your view templates (usually it would be used in the layout). Install the [**debug kit**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#debug-kit) plugin for better/more inspection capabilites, and enable logging in your database server to check what exactly is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code may solve your issue

```
$this->Logging->save($logging_values['Logging']);
```